# How can I react to a specific List Item of an Vue List Group with a response of an API call?

Tags: vue.js, frontend

Like Once Approved a request in a list, I want to react to that particular item with Success or Failure of Approval.
Please see below image where I want to make button green on approval Success, after making a successful API Call with server

[Check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkKQK.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help if you didn't share any code,
But you can check this example:

```
<template>

<!-- Your list -->
<ul>
   <li v-for="item in items">
       {{ item }}
       <button @click="approve(item)" :class="{'success': item.approved}">Approve</button>
       <button @click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
   </li>
</ul>
</template>
<script>

<!-- In your script -->
methods: {
  approve(item) {
     // Example using axios for api call
     axios.post('/api/do-something').then(response => {
        
        // Yaaay! success
        item.approved = true;

        // Now check this property to inject the success button class.
     }
  }
}

</script>
```